# Unable to understanding DMZ

Tags: networking, dmz

Could anyone please explain if by default (firewall application) all users can access DMZ? Or only inside users? Also, if the users will be added to the access control list?

Answer (score 1):

The most common form of a DMZ is a kind of "proxy" network between your intranet (LAN) where all your clients are connected to and the WAN. Imagine you have a network with some web servers, PCs like laptops or workstations, and some other servers or services with databases or similar. In front of your LAN, there´s a firewall creating the gateway to the WAN.

If everything is inside the same network you'll have security issues since, if one machine gets compromised, basically everything will be possible.

As long as you're communicating in the same subnet, let´s say a class C network of 192.168.0.0 (IP-Range from 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254) the traffic will not be routed to your gateway which is usually your firewall. Meaning that every request you do from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.3 will not be monitored and/or restricted by your firewall. This is an issue.

Web servers for instance have to be accessible from the outside. If an attacker gets access to the server he could mess with anything in your network.

Now you introduce a DMZ, basically a proxy network between your LAN and the WAN (at least in most cases). Since it's an own subnet the traffic will be routed through your gateway (firewall) so your rules apply. Also, to get into the intranet the data has to pass two firewalls (or twice the same firewall). You can now create firewall rules that will allow or disallow the communication from servers or clients and vice versa in the DMZ to your actual LAN. This way you can define that every communication into your LAN is denied by default and then you start adding rules to allow communication, for instance, if some service has to connect to a database in your LAN or similar.

Many networks only filter inbound traffic that way but in my opinion, you should also deny all outbound traffic until approved by a firewall rule.

Also, depending on the situation, often the clients are in the DMZ as well-meaning only critical infrastructure is in your actual intranet. In this case, commonly only administrative users will have "full" access to the intranet itself. Generally, it's a good idea to put the clients in a separate, restricted network since you'll often get to points where the clients are the biggest vulnerability for your network (Like users who like to open word documents clearly being some kind of fraud and similar)

Comment: (Consider using a spelling checker: connnected, fireall, seperate, ofter)